# Can Fable emit TypeScript or TypeScript type definition files?

Tags: f#, fable-f#

I'm experimenting with Fable. If I type `dotnet fable --help` I see there is a `--lang` switch for TypeScript, and it is described as experimental. So I tried `dotnet fable watch src --run webpack-dev-server --lang TypeScript` but it doesn't seem to do anything different - still generates .js files. I tried to change the `-e` flag to `-e .fs.ts` but that didn't seem to do anything either so maybe I'm not using the switches properly. I searched the Fable compiler issues and didn't see much about TypeScript other than some issues saying they don't support it well, or maybe there was a regression recently. Can't get an answer to what I assume would be a very common question.

Can Fable create TypeScript or TypeScript type definition files?
If so, how do I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the current state of Typescript support is a work in progress that is not actively being developed. Some things may work just fine but it is unlikely you'll get anything larger than a toy application to compile successfully
See: https://github.com/fable-compiler/Fable/issues/1887

Answer (score 3):

Got it to kind-of work by going into the src folder and typing the command `dotnet fable --language TypeScript --typedArrays false App.fsproj`. Don't know how to add this to the package.json script. Also get an error in the typescript when importing int32. But getting farther along.